# How to include default and timeout for pause--prompt in ansible task

Tags: ansible

during a playbook run, I need to get user input.

It can only be run during the playbook run since I need to check if the file exists. if exists I will need to issue a prompt that asks the user to click 1 or 2. - I have managed to do this but I need to ass 2 more options to the prompt

1. The prompt pause should **wait for 10 seconds only**
2. If after 10 seconds the user didn't put any input the **default will be "1"**

> ```
>   - name: generate_private_key
>     pause:
>       prompt: "Key exists, click [1] to skip the key creation or click [2] to re-create the 
>                key - This will require you to distribute the keys"
>       #default: 1  ### This is not working, saying it is not supported by a pause 
>       echo: true
>     register: crate_key
>      when: is_private_exists.stat.exists == True
> ```

Comment: you couldn't mix prompt with input and pause with time declared, either you have a prompt with input either you have a pause with message but no input possible...

Comment: Regarding "_If exists I will need to issue a prompt that asks the user to click 1 or 2._", why? Is there any reason why this can't be answered in advance? In example, "Re-create PrivKey if exists (Y)?" before the playbook run starts.

Comment: @U880D I need to check if the file exists, If it exists the user should choose to recreate the key or to skip

Comment: There is no need to check if the file exists and ask then as it is easily possibly to ask and choose before. Nothing in logic or behavior would change.

Answer (score 0):

A task timeout is added in 2.10 release.

For example, below playbook fails in 2.10 version:

```
- name: generate_private_key
  prompt: "Key exists, click [1] to skip the key creation or click [2] to re-create the 
            key - This will require you to distribute the keys"
  default: 1
  register: crate_key
  when: is_private_exists.stat.exists == True
  timeout: 10
```